# automating nginx/passenger installation

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger, ansible

I am trying to automate the nginx/passenger installer by running the following command:

```
passenger-install-nginx-module --auto --auto-download --extra-configure-flags=none --languages ruby
```

I am configuring my server using Ansible so have a task that runs that command. The task runs but never finishes. I cannot see if the installer is awaiting an answer for anything but my guess is that it may be but I don't know what?

I ran the command with `--help` which gave me a list of the flags to pass to the command which are all set up but it makes no difference.

Any ideas on what it may be waiting for?

The Ansible tasks is below:

```
- name: Passenger and Nginx
  shell: bash -lc "passenger-install-nginx-module --auto --auto-download --extra-configure-flags=none --languages ruby"
```

Comment: Maybe it's just taking a long time compiling?

Comment: If that's correct then it's still going from when I posted the message.

Comment: I formatted my server and started afresh and ran my Ansible script and the passenger/nginx interactive installer started and the answers I gave were executed automatically but I hadn;t installed rack. I moved the install rack task before the passenger/nginx task in my playbook and re ran it but now it just stops without showing the installer. I'm guessing it's due tot he fact that it has partially been installed. How can I get it to do it fully over again without having to resort to formatting the server and starting a fresh?

Comment: Have you tried copy-pasting the passenger-install-nginx-module command in your SSH terminal shell and observing what happens?

Comment: Ah, Just tried that and it's got stuck at `Where do you want to install Nginx to?` It doesn't seem to be auto continuing like it should. Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at existing role at https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/182

Comment: You need to specify `--prefix` too. Test it on the shell until it's fully automatic.

Comment: What would I set --prefix to then? I thought I didn't need that option?

Comment: Set it to whatever directory you want to install the nginx passenger module at.

Answer (score 0):

> it's got stuck at Where do you want to install Nginx to? It doesn't seem to be auto continuing like it should. Any ideas?

As in help, passenger-install-nginx-module seems need `--prefix=` instead
of asking for it interactively

```
> passenger-install-nginx-module --help
Usage: passenger-install-nginx-module [options]

Options:
    --auto                       Automatically confirm 'Press ENTER to
                                 continue' prompts.
    --prefix=DIR                 Use the given Nginx install prefix instead
                                 of asking for it interactively.
    --auto-download              Download and install Nginx automatically,
                                 instead of asking interactively whether to
                                 download+install or to use an existing
                                 Nginx source directory.
    --extra-configure-flags=STRING
                                 Pass these extra flags to Nginx's
                                 'configure' script, instead of asking for
                                 it interactively. Specify 'none' if you
                                 do not want to pass additional flags but do
                                 not want this installer to ask
                                 interactively either.
    --languages NAMES            Comma-separated list of interested
                                 languages (e.g.
                                 'ruby,python,nodejs,meteor')
```